# Presenting: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "failed to compile bitcode for myApp:

Tags: ios, bitcode, xcode7.3, ios9.3

I have Meet a Problem When I Update Xcode From 7.2.0 to 7.3.0 ,I use Archive to Generate ipa For my App ,In the last step  ,I select Rebuild from bitcode ,Then show  Preparing  Archive interface ,but I get a error "failed to compile bitcode for myAppName:" 
I did  enable bitcode in my project.

Dose Anybody Know how to slove such a  problem.

Comment: Looks like you're having the same problem as me (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324228/bundled-framework-issues-with-bitcode-compilation). Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. and I asked the Apple Developer Relations, They advised me to download the latest Xcode 7.3.1 GM Seed， from the link:
Xcode 7.3.1 GM Seed - 7D1012
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/
Now it ok. Wish to help.