# Bundled framework issues with Bitcode compilation

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

I have a watchOS app which includes a framework. Suddenly with Xcode 7.3, I have been having issues with Release builds.

I had to follow the manual instructions found [here](https://medium.com/@heitorburger/static-libraries-frameworks-and-bitcode-6d8f784478a9#.57usvrxsl) to solve my Release build issues. My app compiles on all build configurations now. When I try to export my app from the Xcode Organizer, I'm faced with other errors.

From the very verbose console output, I found the last error message in the process:

> description = "failed to compile bitcode for Coventry-Watch:\n    Debug: SDK path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS2.2.sdk\n    Debug: PATH: ['/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin']\n    Debug: Using: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo\n    MachoInfo: cd /\n    \"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo\" \"-info\" \"/var/folders/bk/lqjcpcfx0g1g2_k4bp49ppq00000gr/T/ipatool20160331-56415-1e0ofzg/thinned/armv7k/Payload/My App.app/Watch/My Watch App.app/PlugIns/My Watch App Extension.appex/Frameworks/Coventry-Watch.framework/Coventry-Watch\" \n
>   ...

I can't work out what has changed in between Xcode versions to suddenly cause an issue. I think I understand the error, but I don't know what might need fixing to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provide, I understand that the framework included by your app is "built by an Aggregate target, which has a custom Run Script to build a "fat" (simulator+device) version of it".

If this is the case, your bitcode-missing issue may come from the same problem described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184930/xcodebuild-7-3-cant-enable-bitcode/36248115#36248115).
And the workaround for it is to add the following line at the beginning of your Aggregate target script:
`unset TOOLCHAINS`

Comment: Thanks, but I actually don't have an aggregate target. I have a Framework target which is included in my watchOS extension.